# Is it possible to live "off-grid" in the modern world while still having access to a full range of facilities

Tags: finances, identity

Imagine someone wanting to live in and around one big city, like London or New York, while concealing both all traces of their real identity and - crucially - where they lived. The latter to the point where they might find it sensible not to have a fixed home but to move around a lot using hotels and B&Bs, maybe even sleeping rough some of the time. The idea is that they don't want anyone to know exactly where they might be at any given time.

However, this individual is also quite wealthy, and they want to enjoy some of the benefits of that wealth. They can't buy a house and live there, but to have access to their money while moving around a lot, they'd need bank accounts and possibly credit cards. They'd probably need IDs like a driving license and passports. They want to be contactable, so they'd need mobile phones and, quite possibly, an address to receive documentation.

As someone who lives a wholly humdrum and unremarkable life, it seems almost impossible to reconcile these two scenarios, but it's something I'd like to do for a character in a story. I'm just not sure how they could realistically go about it: it seems to me that it'd be incredibly difficult to maintain fake IDs and addresses to conceal one's identity while also registering for modern services like bank accounts and mobiles and having no fixed address.

Is this possible? How would someone go about it?

Comment: ??? Why don't they just rent an appartment for the purpose of showing an address to the authorities and simply not live there? When you go get a driving license or identity card or bank account they don't send anybody to check that you actually live at the indicated address.

Comment: you mean behind bars?

Comment: Cameras everywhere and facial recognition burgeoning?

Comment: I remember 'Necessity' by Brian Garfield doing a great job with this sort of story. In this case it is someone who has to disappear with a child and a suitcase of mafia money, It came out in the 1980's which is pretty 'off the grid' by todays standards, but a good read none the less.

Comment: @AlexP "Why don't they just rent an apartment for the purpose of showing an address" I thought that was what parents were for? ;P .. renting one is an expensive way to go, several people could share (and not live in) a single flat for that purpose but a post box would be cheaper and might suffice in place of a flat for some jurisdictions.

Comment: @Pelinore: The question specifies that *"this individual is also quite wealthy"*.

Comment: [reads question .. ponders] You know what bells this is ringing for me? White Wolf VTM, one way or another living off grid in a city issues were often half of any game time and very often much more than half of your downtime stuff.

Comment: @AlexP So is Musk [wealthy that is] .. he reportedly does (or did?) it by hitting up friends and associates couches (or in his case more likely the guest room or pool house) though I have no doubt he spent a lot of time in high end hotels as well, is he still doing that or has he bought a home yet?

Comment: @Pelinore: I am not current with the personal life of Mr. Musk. As far as I know, he did indeed buy a [50,000 USD portable house](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JMrfSFQdpo) from [Boxabl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxabl). But again as far as I know he continues to sleep wherever he is when he needs to sleep.

Comment: This does not appear to be about worldbuilding, it is about a single character's actions in the real world, which are specifically off-topic for this site.  (Additionally, without defining what "quite wealthy" means to an order of magnitude, what aspect of their "real" identity they are trying to conceal and who they are trying to evade, there are insufficient details to give a good answer.  The details are irrelevant when the basic subject is off-topic though.)

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Thanks - I didn't realise. I'll flag my own question

Answer (score 6):

When someone is wealthy, then this can all be done by using other people. One has a servant through whom all outside transactions happen. That person knows how this someone wants to contact and can provide the phones, the cash, and sign for the multiple leases of places to live. By having multiple places and sufficient cash to swiftly rent a room for the night, nobody will know where this someone is. The someone will contact their servant to set a place and time to meet and transfer cash and a new phone.

Within a large metroplex, there are sufficient transportation possibilities that take cash. There are also many places to stay that take cash and don't ask questions about who you really are.

Comment: Any relative, friend or acquaintance (paid or not) works as well as a servant, all you need is a smartphone they can contact you on and they can scan any letters or documents and email them to you, if you want the phone off grid as well just use a pay as you go one with no service contract or registered details .. they or another can even provide a bank card for an account not in your name money goes into so you don't need lots of cash on you all the time but that does mean you have to trust them with unsupervised access to at least some of your wealth .. a law firm might be a good option.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, but if you want access to your wealth without that being 'on grid' (such that your location, cash withdrawals and purchases weren't recorded against your name somewhere and could be easily accessed by anyone) you will need help from someone who is "on grid"

Any relative, friend or acquaintance (paid or not) that you can trust would do, all you need is a smartphone they can contact you on and they can scan any letters or documents and email them to you, if you want the phone off grid as well just use a pay as you go one with no service contract or registered details .. they or another can even provide a bank card for an account not in your name they feed money into (deposited as cash if you want to avoid links between this account and your wealth) so you don't need lots of cash on you all the time, but that does mean you have to trust them with unsupervised access to at least some of your wealth.

..

You might want to change the phone and the card account occasionally if you're worried about people linking them to your identity and then being able to see some "on grid" footprint for you through them.

If you're worried about anyone using brute force data analysis to extrapolate an "on grid" footprint for you out of the data from everyone and everything else all you can do is switch things up regularly, move often and not always do the same things and go to the same places.

It's best that this individuals link to you is not commonly known and the information you are trying to hide can still be extracted from them by authorities if the law gives them that right, but going 'offshore' to another country for this person can make that more difficult.

A law firm, maybe in another country (particularly one with appropriate privacy laws that doesn't cooperate with your home countries law enforcement agencies if that's a thing you're worried about), might be a good option for what you want, and splitting the card and phone provider (using different people for each) adds a further layer of security.

..

Aside from any of that obviously use cash rather than the card as much as possible.

It won't be perfect, but it will reduce your 'on grid' footprint to a minimum and make it very difficult for anyone to follow you or your personal activities through it.

Comment: I got carried away there, this all comes very close to a lot of old ideas for VTM characters back in the day, how does a hundred year old immortal being even 'have' vast wealth in the modern day without everyone knowing he exists and who he is was a bit of a problem when you start to think about it :)

Answer (score 4):

### You don't need to actually move around a lot to stay off the grid

All you need is a sketchy landlord and cell phone provider.

Instead of buying a house or renting an apartment through a reputable company, you can simply rent property from any random person who feels good about a little tax evasion.  A random person looking to make some extra money would be more than happy to take payments in cash so that they don't have to claim thier earnings.  And for you trying to live off the grid, that means that you name is not associated with your actual address.  Your landlord can include utilities with your rent so that your name does not need to be on any of the services either.

You would think that the harder part to keep hidden is your GPS location, but with the right cell phone provider, this is not a problem.  I was once in a cell phone store where the guy in front of me bought a cellphone plan under the name Bugs Bunny and an address somewhere on Fake St.  As long as the you find a place where the person behind the counter adequately hates thier job or really needs that commision, they just won't care if you can prove your identity or place of residence.  So sure, there will be A cellphone that can be tracked to your location, but it does not need to be attached to any real PII.

#### Why not just have a friend buy things for you?

This will depend a lot on WHY you are off the grid.  If your main character is just an eccentric millionaire who values his privacy, then yes: it's best to keep everything legal and just go through a proxy to buy you things, but this method falls apart too easily if you are actually a wanted man.  If you wanted by the police, or anyone willing to put down some money for a PI, you will be too easy to find.  All your friends, co-workers, family, and anyone else you can trust enough to keep your secret will be too closely associated with you.  A few wiretaps or a forensic accountant later, and you will not be hard to find.

The advantage of connecting with a sketchy vendor directly is that they are not already known associates of yours; so, investigators will not have a good starting place to even begin to track you down.

### If moving around a lot is important for plot reasons, buy an RV

While an RV won't be as luxurious as a permanent home, it does come with the advantage that you never need to actually pick a spot to live.  You can just drift from campground to truckstop, and never stay anywhere long enough to be found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151406/discussion-between-pelinore-and-nosajimiki).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. It's called "Identity Theft".

The "good" thing is that in the USA, most of the official documents that you need to do things like buying homes, opening bank accounts, or similar can all be "regenerated" from one origin document: a birth certificate.

The "classic" way to do this is to find someone who's name matches your presenting gender and who is roughly your age who has recently died. You can do this by scanning obituaries, they're typically public. The more unknown your person is and the smaller their circle of friends/family is, the better.

Next, you want to check that this person isn't already on the government's radar in some way. Check their credit score, make sure they have no outstanding debts, and make sure they've paid their taxes. This can all be done using more-or-less publicly available information, or might cost you a small bit of money in private detective fees.

Once this is all done, you need to acquire their birth certificate and take it as your own. Either find/steal their physical one, or obtain it through some other way. Then, you're basically set. You can use this birth certificate to get yourself a social security number, driver's license, federal tax-ID, whatever. The "Fun" thing is that these documents will all be entirely genuine. You will end up with a real driver's license that has your real photo on it, that should withstand quite a bit of scrutiny.

The biggest issue is that this method of Identity Theft isn't novel, otherwise I wouldn't be outlining it here. The government knows about it, and there are safeguards in place, for example registering social security numbers as "dead" and there are other smaller ways you might get tripped up like if a police officer pulls older drivers license photos, and suddenly sees a completely different person.

Still, with a bit of luck it shouldn't be too inconceivable that your character managed to "slip through the cracks" or just stole the identity of someone who had none to begin with, like that of an Amish person.

Answer (score 0):

These are the problems poor people with no fixed address have.

Consequentially, there are charities and social services that are able to provide a fixed address for people in that situation.

If I were in that situation at present, I would go to a lunch service and ask somebody there if they could point me in the right direction. I might have to look around for a while -- lots of services and charities do just one thing, and aren't set up to offer other services.